# Installing Apache MPM Worker with PHP support on Ubuntu Server 14.04.1

Tags: 14.04, server, apache2, php, lamp

I'm trying to configure mine server to enable the Apache's "worker" version supporting PHP5. I have googled for hours, and all I find is either confusing/vague info. or tutorials for older Ubuntu versions (I don't even have such "conf.d" folder here!).

After the OS installation (including LAMP Server, of course) I have done this:

```
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-fcgid php5-cgi
sudo a2dismod mpm_prefork
sudo a2enmod mpm_worker
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Then all I get is a message like this:

```
* Restarting web server apache2                                         [fail] 
* The apache2 configtest failed.
Output of config test was:
[Tue Dec 23 04:40:25.939993 2014] [:crit] [pid 5992:tid 140022236075904] Apache is running a threaded MPM, but your PHP Module is not compiled to be threadsafe.  You need to recompile PHP.
```

As far as I seen, there's some files needing to be edited, but since these tutorials are for older/other versions, I couldn't even find them. So my question is, where are the files I need to edit, and what do I have to edit in them?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind. Found that installing nginx with php-fpm is far a better and easier option. I'm writing this answer as may be helpful for others